# Recursive rule in ANTLR

Tags: antlr

I need an idea how to express a statement like the following:

```
Int<Double<Float>>
```

So, in an abstract form we should have:

```
1.(easiest case):  a<b>
2. case: a<a<b>> 
3. case: a<a<a<b>>>
4. ....and so on...
```

The thing is that I should enable the possibility to embed a statement of the form `a < b >` within the < .. > - signs such that I have a nested statement. In other words: I should replace the b with `a< b >`. 
The 2nd thing is that the number of the opening and closed <>-signs should be equal.

How can I do that in ANTLR ?

Comment: I forgot to write that I use the newest version, Antlr4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rule can refer to itself without any problem¹. Let's say we have a rule `type` which describes your case, in a minimalist approach:

```
type: typeLiteral ('<' type '>')?;
typeLiteral: 'Int' | 'Double' | 'Float';
```

Note the `('<' type '>')` is optional, denoted by the `?` symbol, so using only a `typeLiteral` is a valid `type`. Here are the synta trees generated by these rules in your example `Int<Double<Float>>`:

[image: Syntax tree for Int<Double<Float>>]

¹: As long some terminals (like '<' or '>') can diferentiate when the recursion stop.

<sub>Image generated by http://ironcreek.net/phpsyntaxtree/</sub>

Comment: And one can find a "real-life" example [in this java grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4#LC254).

See the classOrInterfaceType rule.

Comment: @Mephy: When I test ur solution, e.g. Int<Float<Double>>, then it says: mismatched input '>>' expecting '>'.

Comment: ok, with a whitespace it works. But I do not understand the problem, I guess. Where I can read a something about that to understand that stuff? And is there an option for a lexer which I can use so that the '>>' can also work?

Comment: The C# example grammar only defines the `GT : '>';` token, and uses a parser rule for the `>>` operator: `right_shift: first=GT second=GT {$first.index + 1 == $second.index}? ; // Nothing between the tokens?`